# PNG background image in Firefox 3.5.4

Tags: css, png

Snippet of my CSS:

```
#wrapper div.box {
    background: url('box-bg.png') left top repeat-y;
}
#wrapper div.box h2 {
    background: url('box-top.png') left top no-repeat;
}
```

That doesn't work. Instead of a transparent image it displays the image but with white space in place of transparent background.

If I do:

```
<img src="box-top.png" alt="" />
```

The transparent image shows up correctly. What's casuing this problem?

Comment: The fact that it works from the html but not from the css makes me wonder if the path to the image might be different when referenced from the css as opposed to the html.  Have you used firebug to look at the image using the css pane with the div selected?

Comment: If possible post a link please, that makes it so much easier to analyze the problem.

Comment: Did background-color:transparent work out? I'm asking because you accepted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly giving the elements a "background-color: transparent"?

Comment: Actually the problem was that the div that was bellow the div.box had white background, I just removed that.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Pekka - Is it possible those HTML elements are inheriting a white background color from another CSS rule? You may want to try:

```
#wrapper div.box {
    background: transparent url('box-bg.png') left top repeat-y;
}
#wrapper div.box h2 {
    background: transparent url('box-top.png') left top no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May I ask what browser you are using? IE6 doesn't display PNGs correctly. Also, how are you creating your PNG? If it's Photoshop, make sure you do a Save as Web... or it will not display correctly (transparency issue).